# Initializing a char pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

How is this even possible?

`const char *cp = "Hello world";`

I am currently reading C++ primer and i found this example (I am a very beginner).

Why is it possible to initialize a char pointer with a string? I really can't understand this example, as far as I know a pointer can only be initialized with & + the address of the object pointed OR dereferenced and THEN assigned some value.

Comment: `"Hello world"` This is NOT a string. That's why it's possible.

Comment: In c and c++ string is an array of char element  and array is equal to address of first element

Comment: It's a C-String. At it's core it is just an array of character you cannot modify.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[String literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are really arrays of constant characters (with the including terminator).

When you do

```
const char *cp = "Hello world";
```

you make `cp` point to the first character of that array.

---

A little more explanation: Arrays (not just C-style strings using arrays of `char` but all arrays) naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element.

Example

```
char array[] = "Hello world";  // An array of 12 characters (including terminator)
char *pointer1 = &array[0];  // Makes pointer1 point to the first element of array
char *pointer2 = array;  // Makes pointer2 point to the first element of array
```

Using an array is the same as getting a pointer to its first element, so in fact there *is* an address-of operator `&` involved, but it's implied and not used explicitly.

As some of you might have noted, when declaring `cp` above I used `const char *` as the type, and in my array-example with `pointer1` and `pointer2` I used a non-constant plain `char *` type. The difference is that the array created by the compiler for string literals are *constant* in C++, they can not be modified. Attempting to do so will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). In contrast the array I created in my latter example is *not* constant, it's modifiable and therefore the pointers to it need not be `const`.

Comment: Very kind man, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`"Hello world"` is a read-only literal with a `const char[12]` type. Note that the final element is the NUL-terminator `\0` which the language exploits as an "end of string" marker. C and C++ allow you to type a literal using `"` surrounding the alphanumeric characters for convenience and that NUL-terminator is added for you.

You are allowed to assign a `const char[12]` type to a `const char*` type by a mechanism called *pointer decay*.

Answer (score 0):

> pointer can only be initialized with & + the address of the object pointed

```
int i = 0;
int *pointer = &i;
```

It's correct but it not the only way to initialized pointers. Look at below exmaple.

```
int *pointer;
pointer = (int*)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

It is how you initialized pointers by allocating memory to it.

> How is this even possible?

It works because `"Hello World"` is a string constant. You do not need to allocate this memory, it's the compiler's job.

By the way, always use smart pointer instead of raw pointer if you're using c++.